# Can't build my Selenium Test using pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, maven-plugin

Hi im new in selenium and im trying to build a test using maven. I followed some steps in running/setting up maven via pom.xml file. i tried to updated the Maven project but still the same error is displayed. However, im encountering an error. see details of pom.xml file and the error. Please help im just new in using Selenium Web and just want to learn.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>FAM.Automation.Test</groupId>
  <artifactId>FAM.Automation.Selenium</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
    <jre.level>1.8</jre.level>
    <jdk.level>1.8</jdk.level>
    </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
    <!-- Compiler plug-in -->
      <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
      </configuration>
      <version>3.6.1</version>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Below plug-in is used to execute tests -->
      <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.19.1</version>
      <configuration>
      <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>

        <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suite name="Suite" parallel="none">
            <test name="Test">
            <classes>
            <class name="Automation.fam.test.GoogleHomePageTitle"/>
            </classes>
            </test> <!-- Test -->
            </suite> <!-- Suite -->
            <!-- TestNG suite XML files -->
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
         </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
       <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
       <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
       <version>2.53.1</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.8</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Error when building the test:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building FAM.Automation.Selenium 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ FAM.Automation.Selenium ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) @ FAM.Automation.Selenium ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ FAM.Automation.Selenium ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ FAM.Automation.Selenium ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) @ FAM.Automation.Selenium ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.201 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-09T19:02:34+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project FAM.Automation.Selenium: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test for parameter suiteXmlFiles: Basic element 'suite' must not contain child elements -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginConfigurationException
```

Answer (score 0):

`suiteXmlFiles: Basic element 'suite' must not contain child elements`

I think you should not use 
`<suite ...` 
inside 
`<suiteXmlFiles>`

Use `<suiteXmlFiles>` to include a file.
Ref:
http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html

Comment: oh yes. sorry. btw, do i need to download the testng.xml file? If yes, where can i download it?

Comment: I don't think we you should download it as much as you want to create it. It will contain the test cases to run. Check here for example:
http://www.seleniumeasy.com/maven-tutorials/choose-selected-testng-xml-files-to-execute-using-maven